# angular 5 Splice not working while data filtering

Tags: angular

Can anyone please tell me i tried to splice the checkbox value. But not working.

> my component.ts

```
articleCategories(e, cat_name) {
    if (e.checked) {
      // this.FiletredCategories.push(cat_name);
      this.articleDetails.forEach((card) => {
        card.article.forEach((obj) => {
          obj.content.forEach((obj1) => {
            let v = obj1.content;
            if (v.toLowerCase() === cat_name.toLowerCase()) {
              this.isShow = true;
              this.FiletredCategories=card;
            }
            else{
              let index = this.FiletredCategories.indexOf(cat_name);
              this.FiletredCategories.splice(index, 1);
            }
          });   
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

In my ts file what i checked that values are sending to FiletredCategories for filtering. If i use this.FiletredCategories.push(cat_name); then splice is working but checkbox filtering is not working

> my component.html

```
<div class="panel panel-default qk_li">
            <mat-list class="mat-list" role="list">
              <mat-list-item style="height: 25px;font-size: 14px;" *ngFor="let speciality of allCategories"
                class="form-check-input" role="listitem">
                <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="speciality.checked" (change)="articleCategories($event, speciality.cat_name)">{{speciality.cat_name}}</mat-checkbox>
              </mat-list-item>
            </mat-list>
          </div>
```

Comment: Define *"not working"* please - any console errors? Provide a stackblitz if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.splice()` you can look for `.filter()` the collection and reassign:

```
this.FiletredCategories = this.FiletredCategories.filter(cat => cat.cat_name !== cat_name);
```

<sup>*If you share your data structure then it would be nice to answer it properly. It is just based on your posted code.*</sup>

Comment: my collection name is subject_categories
and my data structure is 
_id:ObjectId("123")
cat_name:"Aging"

_id:ObjectId("456")
cat_name:"Alchoholism"

    //getting Subject categories from API
    this.dataService.getSubjectCategories().subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.allCategories = response;
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err.message);
      });